# scala-xml child method from an xml node gets trailling white space

Tags: scala, scala-xml

I am actually working on windows and I have to parse xml from a file.

The issue is when i parse the root element, and get the children via the `child` method, I am getting empty children.

```
XML.load("my_path\\sof.xml").child

res0: Seq[scala.xml.Node] = List(
    , <b/>, 
)
```

This is my xml file

```
sof.xml
<a>
    <b></b>
</a>
```

But when I remove every \n and \r of the file like this :

```
sof.xml
<a><b></b></a>
```

I got the following result which is expected

```
res0: Seq[scala.xml.Node] = List(<b/>)
```

My question is, is there an option to read it correctly from the intended form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is the newlines/whitespace are treated as Text nodes. The `scala.xml.Utility.trim(x: Node)` method will remove the unnecessary whitespace:

```scala
scala> val a = XML.loadString("""<a>
     |     <b></b>
     | </a>""")
a: scala.xml.Elem =
<a>
    <b/>
</a>

scala> scala.xml.Utility.trim(a)
res0: scala.xml.Node = <a><b/></a>
```

Note that this differs from the .collect method if you have actual Text nodes inbetween elements, e.g.:

```scala
scala> val a = XML.loadString("""<a>
     |    <b>Test </b>   Foo    
     |    </a>""")
a: scala.xml.Elem =
<a>
   <b>Test </b>   Foo
</a>

scala> scala.xml.Utility.trim(a).child
res0: Seq[scala.xml.Node] = List(<b>Test</b>, Test)

scala> a.child.collect { case e: scala.xml.Elem => e }
res1: Seq[scala.xml.Elem] = List(<b>Test </b>)
```

Using .collect method, the "Foo" string is excluded from the children list.

Comment: Thanks for the complete answer, the trim method was exactly what I was looking for, it also removes the trailling whitespace for xml with bigger depths.

Answer (score 1):

I checked that with this on Mac:

```
XML.loadString("""<a>
                   |    <b></b>
                   |</a>""").child
```

This results in the same behavior - which I also not understand.

However this can fix this in your code:

```
XML.loadString("""<a>
                   |    <b></b>
                   |</a>""").child
  .collect{ case e: Elem=> e}
```

This will eliminate the `xml.Text`s.

Comment: Thanks for the quick fix, but it's annoying to do this each time I need to remove the white space (and I need to do it a lot)
Someone explained why, you should check it out :)